# Object Classifier implies Univalence in Type Theory?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

There is a correspondence between univalence in Type Theory and object classifiers in $\infty$-toposes. This, for example, is suggested in the article [Univalent Foundations for Mathematics](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/univalent+foundations+for+mathematics) on nlab.

Section 4.8 of the HoTT book describes how univalent universes $\mathcal U$ give rise to object classifiers in Type Theory
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\theta_f}>> \mathcal U_\bullet\\
@V{f}VV @VV{\texttt{pr}}V \\
B @>>{\chi_f}> \mathcal U
\end{CD}$$
where $ \mathcal U_\bullet :\equiv \sum_{A \, : \, \mathcal U} A $ is the type of pointed types and $ \texttt{pr} $ the corresponding projection, $ A : \mathcal U $ and
\begin{equation}
\chi_f(b) \equiv \texttt{fib}_f(b), \qquad \theta_f(a) \equiv \big( \texttt{fib}_f(f \, a), (a,\texttt{refl}_{f \,a}) \big).
\end{equation}

Does the other direction also hold? Is it possible to show that a universe $ \mathcal U$ in Martin-Löf Type Theory is univalent, assuming that the canonical projection $ \texttt{pr} : \sum_{A\, : \, \mathcal U} A \to \mathcal U $ is an object classifier in the sense of section 4.8 of the HoTT book?

A naive idea I have considered is to put the function $ \texttt{idtoeqv} : (A=_{\mathcal U} B) \to (A \simeq B) $, or $ \texttt{i} $ for short, on the left of the pullback,* as in the following diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A=_{\mathcal U} B @>>> \mathcal U_\bullet\\
@V{\texttt{i}}VV @VV{\texttt{pr}}V \\
A \simeq B @>>{\chi_\texttt{i}}> \mathcal U
\end{CD}$$
hoping that $ \chi_{\texttt{i}} $ factors through $ \texttt{pr}$, so that the universal property of the pullback will produce a candidate for the quasi-inverse. This approach failed however, since given an $ f : A \simeq B$, I must already have a path $ p : A =_{\mathcal U} B $ in the fiber $\texttt{fib}_{\texttt{i}}(f)$ at hand, in order to define the factorization $ (A \simeq B) \to \mathcal U_\bullet$ in the first place.

*Here I'm assuming that the universe is closed under identity types, i.e. $ A =_{\mathcal U} B : \mathcal U $. It sounds like a desirable property for a universe to have, but I don't know if this is included in Homotopy Type Theory or if this leads to any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you said "object classifier in the sense of section 4.8", I'm going to assume that the other lemmas in that section - in particular, lemma 4.8.3, are fair game. It should be possible to recover it from 4.8.4, but I haven't formalised that.

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to prove univalence from *just* the lemmas in this section; You also appear need **propositional extensionality** and **function extensionality**. Using these three assumptions, we can establish univalence as follows:

We have a function $\chi : (\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} (A \to B)) \to B \to \mathcal{U}$, which by lemma 4.8.3 is an equivalence. Recall that this function is $\lambda\ (E , f)\ x. \mathrm{fibre}_f(x)$. We can use this result to conclude that "maps with $P$-fibres", for our choice of $P$, are classified by the object $\sum_{(A : \mathcal U)}P(A)$. For this, let $P : \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}$ be a predicate on types, and observe that lemma 4.8.3 + some pair munging gives us the following chain of equivalences

```
(Σ[ A ∈ Type _ ] Σ[ f ∈ (A → B) ] ((x : B) → P (fibre f x)))       ≃
(Σ[ (x , f) ∈ Σ[ A ∈ Type _ ] (A → B) ] ((x : B) → P (fibre f x))) ≃
(Σ[ A ∈ (B → Type _) ] ((x : B) → P (A x)))                        ≃
(B → Σ P)
```

Where we go from the first line to the second by rearranging pairs (associativity of $\sum$; exercise 2.10), from the second to the third using our equivalence $\chi$ on the index type (exercise 2.17), and the last uses the "type-theoretic axiom of choice", theorem 2.15.7, applied backwards.

We know that the equivalences are precisely the maps with contractible fibres (theorem 4.4.5); We will show that the type $\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} A \simeq B$ is contractible. Using the equivalence above, and the closure of h-levels under retracts, we can reduce this to showing

$$
\mathrm{isContr}\ (B \to \sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} \mathrm{isContr}(A))
$$

By our assumption of function extensionality, it suffices to show that the codomain type is contractible; Since a contractible type is an inhabited proposition, it suffices to show that it is a proposition (it is inhabited by the unit type). For this, let $(A, c)$ and $(B, c')$ be two contractible types (and the witnesses that they are contractible): we have maps $A \to B$ (resp $B \to A$) sending everything to the centre of contraction of $B$ (resp $A$), so by propositional extensionality, $A = B$; Since $\mathrm{isContr}$ is a family of propositions, the claimed result follows.

We now know that $\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} A \simeq B$ is contractible, and since the map $(-)^{-1} : (A \simeq B) \to (B \simeq A)$ is an equivalence, so is $\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} B \simeq A$; To show that $\mathrm{pathToEquiv}$ is an equivalence, it suffices to show it induces an equivalence of total spaces (theorem 4.7.6), i.e. we need

$$
\left(\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} (B \simeq A)\right)\simeq
\left(\sum_{(A : \mathcal{U})} (B = A)\right)
$$

But we've just established that the left-hand-side type is contractible, and the right-hand type is contractible by path induction, so we are done. I do not know if it's possible to show univalence from the existence of an object classifier *without* the use of function and propositional extensionality, but I suspect that it *isn't*. As for the adequacy of this proof, funext and propext hold in any $(\infty,1)$-topos.

Apologies for the use of monospaced text, I couldn't get `array` to render properly. I've also formalised this argument in Cubical Agda, avoiding the fact that univalence is a theorem. In particular, the file begins with a postulate for lemma 4.8.3, and a postulate of propositional extensionality: [You can check it out here](https://1lab-wip.amelia.how/wip.objectclassifier.html#1429).

**Quick edit**: While universe types aren't *directly* closed under paths, they are *essentially* closed under paths, in that while $A =_\mathcal{U} B$ is a large type, it is equivalent to the small $A \simeq B$. (I can't comment, my account is new)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write down such a detailed answer and thank you also for sharing your formalized solution! The use of the other results in section 4.8 and specifically the equivalence $\chi$, giving the uniqueness of classifying maps, could be expected I think, since that's where univalence flows in. I must admit I was hoping for a more ``categorical solution'' which makes use also of the pullback (probably because I feel more comfortable with category theory) but your neat solution definitely answers the question!

Comment: As a followup, why does function extensionality hold in every ($\infty$,1)-topos? Thinking of it as the analogue of the well-pointedness axiom in (ordinary) topos theory, I would have expected it to be something that must be imposed as an additional axiom also in the ($\infty$,1)-world.

Comment: I was going off result 2.2 here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+extensionality since I'm not too familiar with reasoning externally about higher topoi. Additionally, every 1-topos validates funext for its internal language: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257747/does-the-internal-logic-of-a-topos-satisfy-propositional-functional-set-extens

Comment: Isn't what you're calling 4.8.2 actually 4.8.3?

Comment: @MikeShulman Oops, you're right - fixed, thanks!

Comment: @TJM Function extensionality has nothing to do with well-pointedness. Categorically, function extensionality is the statement that the (locally) cartesian-closed exponential objects satisfy a full universal property rather than just a weak one.  Well-pointedness is undetectable to the internal logic, it's more about the interaction of internal and external properties.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks for the explanations! This might be worth a separate question, but is there a simple answer as to which external features are detected by the internal language and vice versa? Or maybe you're aware of a reference addressing this question? Also, just to make sure I understand, what do you mean by weak vs full universal property?

Comment: @TJM By "weak" I mean as in [weak limit](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/weak+limit), with existence but not uniqueness.  In general, the internal language sees properties that are stable under pullback and descent.  One way of making this precise is with the Kripke-Joyal semantics version of internal logic, or more generally the [stack semantics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802).

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you very much! I will check out your stack semantics paper as soon as possible!

Comment: @AméliaLiao Somewhat belated, thank you too for your comment with the links!

Comment: The fact that function extensionality holds in every ∞-topos is explained in Appendix A.2 of Marco Vergura's thesis, which is available at https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/etd/6257/ .  This is certainly "well-known," but he carefully interprets the statement and proves it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer, if, instead of assuming the statement of theorem 4.8.3, we assume that $\mathcal U$ is an [object classifier](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28sub%29object+classifier+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) in the sense of higher topos theory (that is, that the projection $\mathcal U_\bullet \to \mathcal U$ is a terminal object in the category of arrows and pullback squares), then we can show that $\mathcal U$ is a univalent universe without relying on propositional extensionality.

The key observation is that a pullback square like

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\theta}>> \mathcal U_\bullet\\
@V{!}VV \lrcorner @VV{\texttt{pr}}V \\
1 @>>{'B'}> \mathcal U
\end{CD}$$

is equivalent to an equivalence $A \simeq B$, and the top map $\theta$ is entirely determined by the equivalence. Thus, since by assumption there is a contractible space of such pullback squares, the space of types equivalent to $A$ is also contractible, which is equivalent to univalence by the standard theory of identity systems.

This argument is formalised in Cubical Agda [here](https://agda.monade.li/ObjectClassifier.html), and does make use of function extensionality.