Extensionality in ETCS
I was studying ETCS set theory when a question came to my mind.
I first recall the necessary definitions.

As it is customary, let's fix a terminal set 1.
An element of a set X is a map from 1 to X.
Two sets X and Y have the same elements if every map is an element of X if and only if is an element of Y.
I say that the extensionality principle is valid in ETCS if, for every two sets, they are equal if (and only if) they have the same elements.

This said, is the extensionality principle valid in ETCS? That is, are two sets having the same elements equal?
If two sets have an element in common, they are the same set (being the codomain of that element). But two non-empty sets have the same elements and still may differ. So my guess would be that the answer is negative.
Is it right?

What precisely do you mean by "having the same elements"? ETCS doesn't have a global membership relation $\in$, so you can't say something like $\forall x. x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B$.

@S.C. An element of a set (at least in the way I mean it) is a map from a prefixed final set (usually indicated as 1) to the set. In what I've said, I've made no reference to relations.

That says what a element is, but it doesn't really say what it means for two sets to have the same elements. Whether the set of functions $1 \to A$ is equal to the set of functions $1 \to B$ depends a lot on how functions are encoded. And typically, you want homsets to be disjoint if possible, so $\hom(1, A) = \hom(1, B)$ if and only if $A = B$.

Also in ETCS we don't really have sets of functions $1 \to A$ — sets are what we're trying to define.

@NaïmFavier Are you referring so S.C.'s hom notation or would this be an (implicit) answer to my question?

@S.C. Two sets have the same elements is every map is an element of one set if and only if is an element of the other. I can easily imagine it as a formula.

Just commenting on @S.C.'s comment. I cannot answer your question because you still haven't defined precisely what you mean by extensionality. Don't just imagine it, edit your question.

@NaïmFavier Done. I hope it's clear now.

For a sense in which ETCS does satisfy extensionality (a category satisfying the axioms of ETCS in particular being a topos), see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257747/does-the-internal-logic-of-a-topos-satisfy-propositional-functional-set-extens part 3.

ETCS, as does every reasonable theory of categories used as a foundation, should not allow you to state that two random objects are equal or not. This condition does violate the principle of equivalence. (There are sources which do not explicitly disallow this condition, though.)
Generally speaking, category theory aims to replace statements such as
$$A = B$$
by statements such as
$$A \cong B,$$
or more precisely:
$$f : A \to B \text{ is an isomorphism}$$
So from this perspective, the question is not well-defined. When interpreted set-theoretically, it might make sense to ask it, but the question will depend on the implementation details of the theory - exactly this is the reason why it should not be a question that can be asked.
Also, the condition that the (meta) sets $\hom(1,X)$ and $\hom(1,Y)$ are equal doesn't make much sense, unless of course $X=Y$ (by which I mean definitional equality, not a statement that $X$ and $Y$ happen to be equal!). Recall that every morphism is supposed to have a distinguished codomain object. But this doesn't really answer your question since this will hold for every object instead of $1$.
The next best thing for extensionality is the ETCS axiom that the topos is well-pointed. In simple terms: two maps are equal when they agree on all elements. It can be shown that this implies that every map which is bijective on elements is already an isomorphism. In particular: if $A$ is a subset of $B$ with the same elements as $B$, then the inclusion $A \to B$ is an isomorphism, meaning $A \cong B$. When doing mathematics which is not set theory, you will notice that this is actually enough to argue with elements.
Finally, notice that for all initial objects $0,0'$ in ETCS, that is, empty sets, both the (meta) sets $\hom(1,0)$ and $\hom(1,0')$ are empty, so "equal" in some sense (disregarding the distinguished codomains here). While it is true that $0 \cong 0'$, we cannot conclude $0=0'$ (if stating this was allowed). To any category with an initial object you can easily adjoin as many copies of the initial object as you like and get an equivalent category.

What makes the difference between a couple of "random objects" and a legit couple of objects?

We can ask if a given morphism between two objects is an isomorphism. If the isomorphism is unique when some properties are satisfied, it is usually safe to write that the objects are equal. For example, every two empty sets (in ETCS) are equal in this sense. When no morphism is given in some context, it is not meaningful to ask if the objects are equal. I know that classical set theory allows it, but it doesn't make sense in category theory.

For example, the question "is the sine function equal to the homology of a sphere?" should not be askable.

If I get it right, your answer to my question (concerns about the principle of equivalence set aside) would be positive since, in your view, two empty sets are equal (by which you mean equipotent or, categorically speaking, isomorphic). So you don't admit there may be two different empty sets, right? Or does this possibility even not make sense in your framework?

I see anyway no fundamental reason. It's basically something like "we don't do that here". Still most logical theories have equality (clearly, between objects of the same type).

To expand on Martin's answer, we are only able to talk about equality of objects if we phrase ETCS in the ambient context of a single-sorted first-order logic with a global equality predicate (the same kind that ZFC lives in). This is arguably a bad place for a structural set theory to live in, and some authors (like Tom Leinster) instead define ETCS as a "dependently typed" first-order theory, so that objects $X$ and $Y$ and morphisms $f : 1 \to X$ and $g : 1 \to Y$ are incomparable for equality. See Does equality between sets contradict the philosophy behind structural set theory?.
But, to answer your question literally, in the usual setting of single-sorted first-order logic, if $X$ and $Y$ "have the same elements" in your sense and we have an element $f : 1 \to X$ (that is, $s(f) = 1$ and $t(f) = X$), then $f$ is also an element of $Y$, hence $Y = t(f) = X$. If $X$ (and $Y$) don't have any elements, then there is no reason for them to be equal (though they will of course be isomorphic). To reiterate, this is a very strange notion to define and think about.
